# Send metrics with pushgateway (Prometheus) using windows console

Tags: windows, console, prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I am trying to send metrics to pushgateway from windows. But I get the following error:

> text format parsing error in line 1: invalid metric name

This is the command I run from the console:

```
echo "some_metric 10" | curl --data-binary @ - http: // localhost: 9091 / metrics / job / some_job
```

How could I send my metrics from windows console?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into the same issue, I guess it has something to do with running it on windows. You can try doing it with a powershell script, this worked for me:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/some_job -Method POST
```

Comment: where and how do you put the payload with the metrics for the request?

Answer (score 1):

I had another error running commands from Windows Powershell using both curl.exe and  Invoke-WebRequest:

```
curl.exe -X PUT -d "some_metric 3.14" http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/some_job

echo "some_metric 10" | Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/some_job -Method POST
```

Here is the error message:

`text format parsing error in line 1: unexpected end of input stream`

I found out that it does not pass line feed which is necessary according to the [official document](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway#command-line):

> Note that in the text protocol, each line has to end with a line-feed character (aka 'LF' or '\n'). Ending a line in other ways, e.g. with 'CR' aka '\r', 'CRLF' aka '\r\n', or just the end of the packet, will result in a protocol error.

so I put a line feed at the end of data, and it works now:

```
curl.exe -X PUT -d "some_metric 3.14
>> " http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/some_job
```

As alternative I could also run with Invoke-WebRequest command:

```
echo "some_metric 20
>> " | Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/some_job -Method POST
```