# send metrics from windows server to pushgateway prometheus

Tags: prometheus-pushgateway

i have configured pushgateway which is up and running. I have windows server i have configured script which would count rest api numbers from log (just 4 digit numbers) and save it in text file. I wanted to send this metric to pushgateway so that i can get grafana dashboard created from prometheus as database. I am getting error, what am i missing.
$number=1234

```
first method 
$number = Get-Content -Path "C:\path\to\your\numberfile.txt" -Raw
$metricString = "custom_metric $number 1"

echo "$metricString" `r`n | Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/your_job" -Method Post

---------------------------------------------------------
second method 
$number = Get-Content -Path "C:\path\to\your\numberfile.txt" -Raw
$metricString = "custom_metric $number 1"

# Send the metric string via Invoke-WebRequest
$metricString | Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/your_job" -Method Post
```

when i run this i get error "text format parsing error in line 1, i found this informative command on other issue,

[Send metrics with pushgateway (Prometheus) using windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818211/send-metrics-with-pushgateway-prometheus-using-windows-console/78045889?noredirect=1#comment137590481_78045889)

my query is if i want to run that command echo then invoke how would i do this, when i try to run echo command then hit shift+ enter go to new line then run | invoke command i am able to send test metric to pushgateway.
how would i do this via script

tried adding 'n' or 'r''n etc to getinto new line still now luck
can some one please help

also how do i send instance Ip while sending alert??

provide more updates above

Answer (score 0):

[Prometheus pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway) accepts metrics in the following format:

```
metric_name{optional_labels} metric_value
```

Where:

- `metric_name` is the name of the metric. For example, `temperature` or `requests_total`
- `{optional_labels}` is optional labels for the given metric. For example, {path="/foo",method="POST"}`
- `meteic_value` is **numeric** value for the metric. For example, `123.456`.

A single request to pushgateway can contain multiple metrics. They must be delimited by newline aka `\n` char. For example:

```
requests_total{path="foo"} 123
requests_total{path="/bar/a/b"} 456
```

Note also that pushgateway doesn't store all the pushed values for the same [time series](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#time-series) - it just keeps the last pushed [sample](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#raw-samples) and returns it to Prometheus when it scrapes the pushgateway. If you want storing all the samples, then try using [/api/v1/import/prometheus](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-import-data-in-prometheus-exposition-format) endpoint at VictoriaMetrics - this is Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on.

P.S. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/) for details on Prometheus data model and key concepts.